# Issue with epoc time to NSDate conversion

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm trying with the below code.

```
long mytime = 1230840000000;
NSDate *eDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:utcEpoc];
```

Result I got is:

```
40973-10-07 08:00:00 +0000
```

Where when I tried with the [online converter](http://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html), I got the below date:

```
Thu, 01 Jan 2009 20:00:00 GMT
```

I am under impression that `NSData` Always stores in GMT time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Divide `mytime` with 1000. `initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` waits for seconds.

Comment: That's "`NSDate`" rather than "`NSData`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple: the time interval is measured in seconds not in miliseconds (like in Java or C++). All you need to do is to remove 3 zeros.

All you need to do is:

```
NSTimeInterval utcEpoc = myTime / 1000.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

mytime is about 1230 billion. There are about 30 million seconds in a year, that makes about 1230 million seconds since 1970. On MacOS X and iOS, time intervals are always double precision numbers counting seconds. Seems your time is milliseconds, so divide it by 1000.0.

To make it more clear, I'd change the variable name to "long timeInMilliseconds", then it will be clear to every experienced MacOS X / iOS developer why it is divided by 1000.